# Compiling wxWidgets 2.9.0 with Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate

Tags: visual-studio, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile wxWidgets 2.9.0 with Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate. When I open the workspace wx.dsw I get a whole list of error messages of the form

> Blockquote
>   wx_wxReges.dsp cannot be opened because its project type (.dsp) is not supported by this
>   Blockquote version of the application

I successfully compiled with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening VC9 (VS2008) version of the file, i.e. `wx_vc9.sln`.